# Local (workbook-specific) functions without using VBA or VSTO

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

I am looking for a way to create workbook-local functions in C++ (unmanaged). VBA is not appropriate for my use case. Unfortunately, that's the only way I know of to create a workbook-local function. (I'm not terribly familiar with VSTO, so there may be a way there, but I cannot used managed code for this.) I know how to create functions as XLLs, and I know how to create an automation addin that exposes functions through IDispatch. However, both of these seem to be for global functions only.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: It might help if you explained why VBA or managed code isn't appropriate.

Comment: VBA can only be constructed programmatically if the "Trust access to the Visual Basic project object model" setting is True. Our client base is enormous (hundreds of thousands of users globally). We cannot ask our users to enable this due to security policies at client sites.

Comment: And we internally have a prohibition against loading the .NET framework inside Excel.

Comment: Also, these details aren't important to answering the question. :)

Comment: Oh! But they are important! Otherwise, how do we know that you don't have an XY problem?? Anyway, .Net doesn't need the "Trust Access to VB Project..." stuff, so it's possible that accessing it via COM Interop with C++ would work just as well. Worth a shot maybe.

Comment: It doesn't. I've already tried that. That setting enables/disables access for all automation clients.

Comment: Perhaps that's because my experience with it is working with an add-in for the VBA editor. I guess it's possible that end routes it... Hmm..

Comment: Good point. That's one approach we haven't tried. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but why would you need to dynamically create the function to begin with? Why can't you just embed the function before distributing the workbook?

Comment: Because the whole point of the thing I'm working on (which is a trade secret, unfortunately) is to dynamically expose functions.

Comment: I can say this much: Users of our software will be the ones writing functions, not us. We just need to provide some necessary plumbing.

Comment: You mean [like this](http://fcell.io/)? Michael, I'm afraid that VSTO is the way to go here, whatever your internal policies about loading .Net are, it's the sensible solution and the right technology for the job. Good luck mate.

Comment: We are aware of FCell and ExcelDNA and ExcelWings. .NET isn't a component of our solution at all, nor is it a component of the end-user-developer solutions we'll be supporting.

Answer (score 2):

**Worksheet != Workbook**

I don't know of any way to create *worksheet-local* functions.

In VBA to expose functions you need a standard module (.bas) without the `Option Private Module` option set, exposing a `Public Function` - that function is usable in every worksheet of the workbook that's containing it.

A worksheet is essentially a class module, and lives as an object instance: its `Public Function` members are therefore not usable as worksheet functions.

Functions are *workbook-local*, not *worksheet-local*.

---

Now, that's probably what you meant anyway, given that the add-in approach is being referred to as creating "global" functions, which are available to all *workbooks*.

As @RubberDuck hinted, creating code via the VBIDE library doesn't require elevation and security settings tweaking if you're extending the VBE itself. [This might help](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/next/RetailCoder.VBE/Extension.cs) (it's the entry point for the add-in @RubberDuck and I are working on). This add-in edits, deletes and adds code in the VBE for a living, and doesn't require tweaking macro security settings.

Comment: Are VBIDE addins loaded when Excel is loaded, or only when the VBA IDE is opened?

Comment: Only when the VBE opens, and depending on loading options (if it's set to manual load, it won't load); that's the `LoadBehavior` setting in the registry  key that's registering the add-in with the VBE. "load on startup" is value `3`

Comment: Damnit. If it's not one thing, it's another. Requiring the user to open the VBA is probably a showstopper.